# Relationship between IDL and c++ source file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, interface

To lean about interfaces, I'm trying to write a test project to implement the IDispatch interface.
So far I've:

- created an MFC dll project in visual studio 2010
- written the following IDL

  ```
  [ uuid(68B0FAE7-3828-415D-94B0-720A007311FF), version(1.0) ]
  library Test
  {
  importlib("stdole32.tlb");
  importlib("stdole2.tlb");
  [ 
      uuid(DD35D282-ABEF-4411-B3D1-B4FD848516A5)  
  ]

  interface _Test : IDispatch
  {

  };
  };
  ```

Created a C header file called Test.h but I'm wandering how I declare this to be linked to the IDL. Any help or hello world tutorials would be great. Thanks

Comment: After you created your .idl file you need to use the MIDL compiler to create the correspondent header and proxy files.

Comment: Test.h is the product of the IDL file.  Along with a type library and proxy/stub code, optional.  Now you need to actually *implement* the methods of the interface.  Which requires adding some first.  You leave the IDispatch implementation to a stock implementation, like ATL's IDispatchImpl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you the

- midl compiler

  It is capable of generating header/sources in c (or C++? don't remember), but most importantly it will get you a typelibrary (tlb) file
- [#import directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

  Will generate c++ definitions for the typelibrary contents.